# Make a Class Method "Template" in GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm still quite new to python with less than a year of experience, and I've been learning it through building a rather large project on google app engine. It's grown to be a behemoth of 10k+ lines of code and html templates, so I'm in the process of refactoring a rather large portion of the code to follow a much more rigorous MVC architecture.

My question is one concerning python directly. I don't know the words to say exactly what I want to build, so I would just like to use an example.

This is my current "basic" code for displaying a view:

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        tUser = users.get_current_user()
        tContext = {
            'user':      tUser,
            'login':     users.create_login_url(self.request.uri),
            'logout':    users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri),
        }

        #User is logged in
        if (tUser):
            #code for loading view information and adding to the context dict
            #CUSTOMIZATION GOES HERE
        else: 
            self.redirect("/")

        tmpl = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logged-in.html')
        self.response.out.write(render(tmpl, tContext))
```

**I would like to take this boilerplate code and abstract it somehow**, maybe with a way of prepending/appending the "customizable" code for each class method?

I think I might be able to use a decorator to do this somehow, but I have no python mentors outside of stackoverflow to point me in the right direction. I would prefer the most pythonic method possible, or at least what's generally considered "best practices" in this situation.

The python version is 2.7.2.

*edit*

Note, if I can do this with decorators, then what is necessary for me to be able to call the decorator from an entirely different class and python file? I would like to be able put my decorators in one file and reference it from elsewhere so my code is as normalized as is reasonable. =)

*edit 2*

This is the testing code that I worked out in the console, and I have to leave for the evening or I would refine it more. However, it appears that this successfully accesses and modifies the class's properties, which is pretty much what I think you need to pull this off in GAE.

```
class Decorators():
@staticmethod
def BeginInit(pInFunction):
    def OutFunction1(self):
        print str(self.innerv)
        pInFunction(self)
    return OutFunction1

@staticmethod
def EndInit(pInFunction):
    def OutFunction2(self):
        self.innerv = 5
        pInFunction(self)
        print "this is test 3"
    return OutFunction2

class Test2Handler():
    innerv = 10
    @Decorators.BeginInit
    @Decorators.EndInit
    def TestPrint(self):
        print self.innerv
        print "this is test 2"
```

Prints

```
10
5
this is test 2
this is test 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using decorators, you could use a base class for your request handlers, like so

```
class HandlerBase(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get_context(self):
        return {}

    def get(self):
        tUser = users.get_current_user()
        tContext = {
            'user':      tUser,
            'login':     users.create_login_url(self.request.uri),
            'logout':    users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri),
        }
        # tContext holds the defaults for your context

        #User is logged in
        if (tUser):
            # if the dict returned by self.get_context() contains a key
            # that's already in tContext, tContext[key] will be overridden
            # with self.get_context()[key]
            tContext.update(self.get_context())
        else: 
            self.redirect("/")

        tmpl = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logged-in.html')
        self.response.out.write(render(tmpl, tContext))


class MainHandler(HandlerBase):

    def get_context(self):
        # the contents of the following dict will be added to
        # the context in HandlerBase
        return {'greeting': 'Hi!'}
```